# How to disable focus in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I created an application but I have a problem with the focus. How can I disable the focus of another main form when the form loads?

Comment: Can you explain your query with a little bit more detail?

Comment: Your question is vague. Do you have any code you could provide us or at least a better explanation?

Comment: You want a non-modal window to get focus when it loads?

Comment: sorry for my question that not clear,i use notification like skype​​ notification when user online it show notification info,so I want you help me, notifaction form do not focus to main form. hope you will understand!

Answer (score 0):

WPF forms have a ShowActivated property. Set this to false and the form won't get the focus.

You may also override the OnActivated method :

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);

        //Set the window style to noactivate.
        WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        SetWindowLong(helper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
            GetWindowLong(helper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
    }   

    private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```

Comment: SHowActivated=false but still focus, but I want to use OnActivated Function,how to call OnActivated function?